# Displaying values on hook_form

Tags: 7, forms, files

I'm displaying a form on admin url :`admin/settings/custom`. In the page argument I pass `array('custom_admin_form'),` to the menu item. In the form function I'm writing form elements to display folder and file names present in the public folder. I get those values through the code below:

```
$dir_path = variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path(). '/files') ;
$fileslist = glob($dir_path . "*.*"); 
$dirs = glob($dir_path . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach($dirs as $directs){
     $names = explode('/', $directs);
     $fnames[] = end($names);
}
```

How can I display the results in the form function? I tried it using `print`, `echo`, `drupal_render` but nothing is working. I've also used `#markup` element, but it was displaying `array()`, not the values of array.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
 $form['sample'] = array(
     '#type' => 'item',
     '#markup' => print_r($sample_values, TRUE),        
 );
```

or simply just

```
print_r($sample_values);
```

or install `Devel` module and use `dsm` function.

```
dsm($sample_values);
```

UPDATE:

Try this:

```
$form['sample'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => print_array_values($sample_values),        
);
```

Then declare the function below:

```
function print_array_values($sample_values){
    $content = '';
    foreach($sample_values as $val){
            $content .= '<div>' . $val . '</div>';
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou sir, but print_r($sample_values); will not display the values where i want to display. is there any way to display  values by using foreach loop for form element.So that for each value it will print value.

Comment: I edit the answer to add the second argument in the print_r function (TRUE), to return the sting instead of printing it.

Comment: @Suraj -> I updated my answer. Anyways, call me Ms. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `dpm` or `dsm` or `kpr`, which is very common among Drupal developer for printing variables to debug in Drupal 7. But you need to enable [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module in your site first as @AlyssaGono suggested.

If you want to use something not depends on other module, you can use `var_dump()`.

Example:

```
var_dump($variable);
drupal_exit();
```